# MacOS Firewall blocks webserver and logging wont work

Tags: macos, network, firewall

Currently I wrote a small game webapp. The server is running on my MacBook Air M1 Sonoma 14.3 and listening on 0.0.0.0:8080. I want to connect to it within my local network from my iPhone.

This works fine until I turn on the system firewall.

I whitelisted the app (called nq_server) in the firewall settings, but this didn't worked. 
I tried to turn on detailed logging using `socketfilterfw`, but `appfirewall.log` remains empty. 
I also tried rebooting after changing the firewall settings.

If I disable the firewall and reboot everything works fine again.

Does anyone have a clue which application I have to whitelist in the firewall and why the logs remain empty?

Comment: Does it work if you bind the server to the local IP address (not 0.0.0.0, not 127.0.0.1) directly?

Comment: I tried it with 192.168.42.117:8080, which is the IP of the Mac, but it also wont work.